# Problem with 2wd bluetooth controlled car cannot stop

Tags: c++, arduino

So I'm creating a code for a 2wd bluetooth controlled soccer car. And when I press forward, it moves forward non stop.

I've tried changing the code a few times like:

```
if( val == '1') // Forward
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
      delay(1);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
    }
```

To:

```
if( val == '1') // Forward
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
    }
```

Heres the full code:

```
// Starting of Program
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10,11);
int m1a = A3;
int m1b = A4;
int m2a = 3;
int m2b = A5;
char val;

void setup() 
{  
pinMode(m1a, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 10 set as output Pin
pinMode(m1b, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 11 set as output Pin
pinMode(m2a, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 12 set as output Pin
pinMode(m2b, OUTPUT);  // Digital pin 13 set as output Pin
mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  while (mySerial.available() > 0)
  {
  val = mySerial.read();
  mySerial.println(val);
  }

  if( val == '1') // Forward
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
      delay(1);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
    }
  else if(val == '2') // Backward
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, HIGH); 
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW); 
    }

    else if(val == '3') //Left
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW); 
    }
    else if(val == '4') //Right
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, HIGH); 
      delay(200);
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW); 
    }

    else if(val == 'S')
    {
      digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
      digitalWrite(m2b, LOW); 
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
    }
}

// End of program
```

No error massage please help....
I'm using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.jahnestacado.arduinorc) on my phone and the last 11 line of code, the (val == 'S') is for a stop button in the app.

I need it to only move if a button is pressed and stop if nothing is pressed. It doesn't need a stop button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( val == '1') // Forward
{
  digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
}
```

To

```
if( val == '1') // Forward
{
  digitalWrite(m1a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m1b, LOW);
  digitalWrite(m2a, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m2b, LOW);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(m1a, LOW);
  digitalWrite(m2a, LOW);
  val = ' ';

}
```